# Phonegap on the iPad: Custom html page?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have a HTML5 App and want to deploy it with Phonegap to iOS devices. The app is designed for smartphones. To make use of the iPad Screen I designed a new layout.

**My idea:**

Two seperate `index.html` files as the starting point for the app.

- `index.html` for Smartphones
- `index-ipad.html` for tablets

How can I make Xcode or Phonegap to load the appropriate html page when starting the app ?

Cheers

Johe

Comment: I'd imagine you could use JavaScript to redirect based off the user agent.

Comment: Sure, but I would prefer a solution which fires before any unnecessary code is beeing run...

Comment: Well, for now this works: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/

Comment: Re: unnecessary code, make index.html do nothing but redirect to an iPad or iPhone version. It'll be minimal work for the webview to perform that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one HTML file with CSS3 media queries doing the different layouts

Answer (score 1):

I would start in Java. Depending on screen size it would call either the `index.html` or `index-ipad.html`. But if you're using Phonegap with proper CSS you should be able to use one `index.html` for both. Phonegap and CSS would do the work.

Comment: JavaScript and Java are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with user899641's suggestion that the device abstraction should be happening at the PG/CSS level, it's fairly trivial to modify the native PG library to do what you ask.  In the case of iOS, `PhoneGapDelegate.m` contains a function called `startPage` which, as written, returns the static string `index.html`.  You can modify this function to apply additional logic and return a different start page accordingly.